# Grouping Android Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

The below code is working fine with me in terms of creating the notification, with its voice and actions.

but looks the `.setGroup(GROUP_KEY_Fonix)` is not working, as the notifications are not grouped together, am I missing something here!

```
public int notificationID = 0;
final static String GROUP_KEY_Fonix = "fonix_notification";

private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage){
    notificationID++;

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

// intent triggered, you can add other intent for other actions
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationView.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

// Build the notification, setting the group appropriately
    Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_Fonix)
            .setContentTitle("New note: " + notificationTitle)
            .setContentText(notificationMessage)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_new_message)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_new_message, "View", pIntent)
            .addAction(0, "Remind", pIntent)
            .build();

// Issue the notification
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // hide the notification after its selected
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notif);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you should create group summary notification. For this just use this code:

```
Notification notificationSummary = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        //Set content
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_Fonix)
        .setGroupSummary(true)
        .build();

notificationManager.notify(notificationSummaryId, notificationSummary);
```

*Learn more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#bundle).*